# How do I derive weights given a weighted average?

Tags: algebra, quantitative-finance, weighted-average

Ok I feel like this has to have a simple solution but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I have a given weighted average, let's say total returns of a portfolio.  And I want to break that out into returns from equity and returns from bonds.  I know the returns of each and my total return, but I don't know how to calculate what weights I had in each.

I know I can use goal seek in Excel to get the answer, but there has to be some calculation I can use.

Ex: Total Return (weighted average of stocks and bonds) = 3.48%, Stock Returns = 5.21%, Bond Returns = 0.59%

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finance / mathematics instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

If  i understand well your question, you want to know how to calculate that the weight of the stock portfolio is 1.67 the weight of the Bond Portfolio.

> 1.0059 bond + 1.0521 stock = 1.0348 ( bond + stock ) and stock = w * bond

after replacing  stock by  w*bond on the first equation, and isolating w , you can find that the initial portfolio contains 1.67 stocks for 1 bond. Hope it helps.